# X-ray pulse more powerful than national grid?

Tags: experimental-physics, x-rays

There is an article today in the BBC science section on the Linac Coherent Light Source, an X-ray laser in Palo Alto: http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-31483781.

I don't trust the news with scientific accuracy, and in this article we have an interesting claim: "Each X-ray pulse has as much power as the national grid of a large country"

How can this be possible? Is the author using the word "power" incorrectly?

Answer (score 5):

I can't find details on the pulse energy and duration of the LCLS, but it's entirely plausible the power could be greater than *the national grid of a large country*. The power is energy divided by time, and if the pulse length is very short then even a modest pulse energy produces an astronomically high power.

For example the laser at the National Ignition Facility only has a pulse energy of a few kJ, but it's delivered in about a picosecond so the power during that time is around 500 terawatts. For comparison, the peak loads on the UK National grid are about 50GW or 10,000 times lower than the NIF power.

**Later:**

The LCLS pulse duration is [around 100 femtoseconds](http://lcls.slac.stanford.edu/WhatIsLCLS_1.aspx). It would only need to deliver 5 milliJoules per pulse to match the UK National Grid power.

**Response to comment:**

Let's be clear on our definitions: the average power is the energy delivered per second while the peak power is the energy delivered in a 100 femtosecond pulse divided by the length of the pulse (i.e. 100 fs).

Let's suppose the peak power equals the UK National Grid power of 50GW, so the energy per pulse is 5 mJ. The LCLS delivers 100 pulses per second, so the energy per second is 0.5 J and the average power is therefore 0.5W, which is somewhat less than the UK National Grid.

The point is that the LCLS delivers very, very high peak power but only for an exceedingly short time.